# It gets caught on an infinite loop

Tags: java

don't know why my code gets caught on an infinite loop..Maybe i wrote the code wrong?or the indentation?
the output didn't give any errors

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Not sure if it's a better way but I did this way:
 final int TRIES = 5;
 int heads = 0;
 for(int i=0; i<=TRIES; i++)
 {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Do you wanna continue? Y or N? ");
     char c = input.next().charAt(0);
     c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
     if(c =='y'){
     int r = (int) Math.random * 2) + 1;   //A number between 1 & 2

       if(r == 1)
       {
        System.out.print("heads");
        heads++;
       }
       else{
        System.out.print("Lost");
       }
    }

     else{
      System.out.print(heads);
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: *"or the indentation"* This just causes problems with StackOverflow users or the code readability, not with the JVM itself.

Comment: There's no infinite loop here. You're going to loop 6 times and be done (after the code is fixed enough to compile).  You aren't doing anything to affect the loop index.  What makes you think you have an infinite loop?

Comment: (Can't delete comment; disregard, I didn't see one of the brackets)

Comment: So can't I use for loops mixed with if-else?

Comment: I misread your code.  The if and for stuff is bracketed "correctly".  Looks like you've got some extra curly braces at the end, though.  Indentation won't break your code, but it can make it difficult to read.  Fix indentation and you'll see where the mismatched brackets are.

Comment: Juan Tomas thanks alot!

Comment: Hmmm... How do you expect `c =='y'` to ever be true after `c = Character.toUpperCase(c)` has changed `c` to a uppercase letter? No uppercase letter can *ever* be equal to a lowercase `y`. --- Did you intend the loop to exit when user answers `n`? If yes, which part of the code do you think is supposed to accomplish that? A `break` statement might be used for that, but I don't see any of those in your code.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't compile.  When fixed it doesn't infinitely loop.  It's unclear what your actual problem is since you haven't provided a [mcve], or a clear description of the behavior you're seeing (i.e. what inputs are you providing?)

Comment: You are calling toUpperCase() on the input so your if condition should be 'if(c=='Y')'. Replace this and it works fine as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure either but I think this code should work fine:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Not sure if it's a better way but I did this way:
        final int TRIES = 5;
        int heads = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<=TRIES; i++) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Do you wanna continue? Y or N? ");
            char c = input.next().charAt(0);
            c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            if(c =='Y') {
                int r = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;   //A number between 1 & 2
                if(r == 1) {
                    System.out.println("heads");
                    heads++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Lost");
                }
            } else {
              System.out.print(heads);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. Answering `N` will still keeping asking the "Do you wanna continue?" repeatedly. --- Also, you didn't explain what you changed and why you did it. In short, the answer is not really that useful. There are at least 2 problems left in that code.

Comment: Thanks alot ..It does compile..my only error was one extra cosing brace.. u helped me alot..I also voted u up

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Not sure if it's a better way but I did this way:
        final int TRIES = 5;
        int heads = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<=TRIES; i++)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Do you wanna continue? Y or N? ");
            char c = input.next().charAt(0);
            c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            if(c =='Y'){
                int r = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;   //A number between 1 & 2

                if(r == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("heads");
                    heads++;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Lost");
                }
            }

            else{
                System.out.println(heads);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but this code compiles, and moreover it stops the loop when you say you don't want to continue. Using break is not the best practice, but it works. It will still only ask a maximum of 5 times, because that is the limit you put in your for (as given by your TRIES variable). If you want to run an infinite loop that stops when the user doesn't want to continue, you migth want to use a boolean variable and a while, like so:

```
    boolean stop = false;
    while(!stop)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you wanna continue? Y or N? ");
        char c = input.next().charAt(0);
        c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        if(c =='Y'){
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;   //A number between 1 & 2

            if(r == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("heads");
                heads++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Lost");
            }
        }

        else{
            System.out.println(heads);
            stop=true;
        }
```

Note that you were turning the input character to uppercase and then comparin it to 'y', which will always be false.

Comment: I like it that u use two methods in solving this problem.. Thanks alot ! Unfortunately I have to choose only one answer..